# Find value from one float in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have one array of value and I want to find what position it has in another array of values.  So for example if I have:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
array2 = [2,6,3,4,1,5,.....]
```

I want to find what position each element from array 1 has in array 2, so I want it to return something like

```
what_position = [4,0,2,3,5,1]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
      what_position = array1[i].index(array[2])
```

but i get an error that says

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Which i guess means I can't use .index on a float.  Is there another way I can go about this.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is provided by `np.intersect1d`:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
array2 = [2,6,3,4,1,5]

np.intersect1d(array1, array2, return_indices=True)[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension helps:

```
positions = [array2.index(item) for item in array1]
```

A for loop with the same result:

```
positions = []
for item in array1:
    positions.append(array2.index(item))
```

In other words, you call `index()` on a list, not on an individual item.

Comment: This has quadratic time, not very efficient

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have repeating elements in `array2` you can use the following solution. It should be faster than the list comprehension with `index()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import count

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array2 = [2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 8]

itemgetter(*array1)(dict(zip(array2, count())))
# [4, 0, 2, 3, 5, 1]
```